# Flattening nested json file with pandas json.normalize()

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, normalization

I have a json file that I can put into data frames, but some of the key values pairs are nested like so

```
{"obj":["id"{ "k1":v1}, 

"kA":value_a, 

kD:{"D":vD},

"listOfKeyVal"[
{

"k1":"v1",
"k2":"v2"
"k3":"v3",
"k4":"v4"
}
],

"kb":"Vb",

"kc":vc"
]
}
```

I opened the file using json.load, and am able to normalize the object with

```
rdf=pd.json_normalize(jobj)
```

However, while the rest of the elements normalize I am still having trouble with the listOfKeyVal being nested It is a list with one dict object that contains numerous key value pairs. I cannot get it to normalize and flatten along with the other key value pairs. I have tried using the following code

```
r1=pd.json_normalize(jobj, record_path=['listOfKeyVal'],
                     meta=["k1",
                           "k2"
                           "k3",
                           "k4"],record_prefix=' ',errors='ignore' )
```

When I run this I get a Keyerror for 'listOfKeyVal', and all of the documentation covers lists with numerous dictionaries not a list with one braced object with numerous key value pairs. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided a valid json object. Can you update the question, fixing the data?

Comment: I am still learning how to use json. If you tell me what makes it invalid id be happy to correct it.

Comment: key:value pairs where keys should have quotes and if you have variables as values, for Stackoverlow make them a number so it's easier to understand, or put them in quotes too as a representative example.  just go pair by pair and be sure the formatting is correct.